# Calling an object of class in another class

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie to OOP. I have worked in procedural programming a lot. So i am in little trouble right now. Can you please tell me how to call an object of a class in another class and then i can access all the variables and function of that class with using that object.

For e.g

I have a class of DBconnection. i write my db queries in it. Now i have an other class named Users. Now i need to access the db queries in User class, definitely i need object of DBconnection class to access all db queries. What can i do please help

The example code which i have written is as below:

```
**DBConnection class**

class DBConnection
    {
        public $SITEURL;
        public $servername;
        public $username;
        public $password;
        public $dbname;
        public $objDbConnect;

        function DBConnection(){
            $this->SITEURL=Configuration::SITEURL;
            $this->servername=Configuration::servername;
            $this->username=Configuration::username;
            $this->password=Configuration::password;
            $this->objDbConnect=mysql_connect($this->servername,$this->username,$this->password);
                if($this->objDbConnect){
                    mysql_select_db($this->dbname);
                }
            }
    function InsertRecord($pStrTableName,$pArrField,$pArrValue)
    {

    $strSql="insert into $pStrTableName (";

    $intFieldSize=count($pArrField);
    for($i=0;$i<$intFieldSize;$i++)
    {
        if($i==$intFieldSize-1)
        {
            $strSql.=$pArrField[$i];
        }
        else
        {
            $strSql.=$pArrField[$i].",";
        }
    }
    $strSql.=") values (";

    $intFieldSize=count($pArrValue);
    for($i=0;$i<$intFieldSize;$i++)
    {
        if($i==$intFieldSize-1)
        {
            $strSql.="'".$pArrValue[$i]."'";
        }
        else
        {
            $strSql.="'".$pArrValue[$i]."'".",";
        }
    }
    $strSql.=")";
    if(mysql_query($strSql))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;   
    }

}

} 

**Users class**

class Users{

        var $username,
            $userpassword,
            $email,


        function User(){

        }


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to use Singleton pattern.
Following is an example

```
class DBConnection
{
    private static $instance = null;

    private function __construct() {

    }

    /*
     * @return DBConnection
     */
    public static function get_db()
    {
        if ( empty(self::$instance) ) self::$instance = new DBConnection();

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function query()
    {

    }
}


class User
{

    function testfunc()
    {
        $db = DBConnection::get_db();
        $db->query();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an object of your class in your second class and use it like

```
$c= new DBConnection();
$c->InsertRecord('Parameters here etc');
echo $c->username; //and other public variables similarly
```

Comment: i can declare $db = new DBConnection in DBConnection class. so if i include DBConnection class in Users class, it can't access the functions and variables.

Comment: why can it not, can you share some code with us which doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

**DBConnection class**

class DBConnection
    {

```
    public $SITEURL;
    public $servername;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $dbname;
    public $objDbConnect;

    function DBConnection(){
        $this->SITEURL=Configuration::SITEURL;
        $this->servername=Configuration::servername;
        $this->username=Configuration::username;
        $this->password=Configuration::password;
        $this->objDbConnect=mysql_connect($this->servername,$this->username,$this->password);
            if($this->objDbConnect){
                mysql_select_db($this->dbname);
            }
        }
function InsertRecord($pStrTableName,$pArrField,$pArrValue)
{

$strSql="insert into $pStrTableName (";

$intFieldSize=count($pArrField);
for($i=0;$i<$intFieldSize;$i++)
{
    if($i==$intFieldSize-1)
    {
        $strSql.=$pArrField[$i];
    }
    else
    {
        $strSql.=$pArrField[$i].",";
    }
}
$strSql.=") values (";

$intFieldSize=count($pArrValue);
for($i=0;$i<$intFieldSize;$i++)
{
    if($i==$intFieldSize-1)
    {
        $strSql.="'".$pArrValue[$i]."'";
    }
    else
    {
        $strSql.="'".$pArrValue[$i]."'".",";
    }
}
$strSql.=")";
if(mysql_query($strSql))
{
    return 1;
}
else
{
    return 0;   
}
```

}

}

**Users class**

class Users{

```
    var $username;
    var $userpassword;
    var $email;
    var $dbcon;

public function __construct()
{
    //create an object
    $this->dbconn = new DBConnection();

    //get user name from dbconnection class
    echo $this->dbconn->username;

}

    function User(){

    }
```

}

//create object for user class

$user = new User();

Answer (score 0):

```
**DBConnection class**

class DBConnection
    {
        public $SITEURL;
        public $servername;
        public $username;
        public $password;
        public $dbname;
        public $objDbConnect;

        function DBConnection(){
            $this->SITEURL=Configuration::SITEURL;
            $this->servername=Configuration::servername;
            $this->username=Configuration::username;
            $this->password=Configuration::password;
            $this->objDbConnect=mysql_connect($this->servername,$this->username,$this->password);
                if($this->objDbConnect){
                    mysql_select_db($this->dbname);
                }
            }

    public static function getConnection(){
        if(!empty($this)){
         return $this;
        }
        return new DBConnection();
    }


    function InsertRecord($pStrTableName,$pArrField,$pArrValue)
    {

    $strSql="insert into $pStrTableName (";

    $intFieldSize=count($pArrField);
    for($i=0;$i<$intFieldSize;$i++)
    {
        if($i==$intFieldSize-1)
        {
            $strSql.=$pArrField[$i];
        }
        else
        {
            $strSql.=$pArrField[$i].",";
        }
    }
    $strSql.=") values (";

    $intFieldSize=count($pArrValue);
    for($i=0;$i<$intFieldSize;$i++)
    {
        if($i==$intFieldSize-1)
        {
            $strSql.="'".$pArrValue[$i]."'";
        }
        else
        {
            $strSql.="'".$pArrValue[$i]."'".",";
        }
    }
    $strSql.=")";
    if(mysql_query($strSql))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;   
    }

}

} 

**Users class**

class Users{

        var $username,
            $userpassword,
            $email,


        function User(){
             $db = DBConnection::getConnection();
             $db->InsertRecord($x, $x, $x);
        }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1 . You can change your class DBConnection to [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). And call your class in User like this `DBConnection::getInstance()->InsertRecord(...)`. It's easy. But not recommended.

2 . You can push your DBConnection instance inside User. Like this

```
class Users{
    var $db_connection;

    function __construct($db_connection){
        $this->db_connection = $db_connection;
    }

$db_connection = new DBConnection(...);
$user = new User($db_connection);
```

3 . You can instantiate new DBCOnnection inside User class. Like in @Sundar answer.

P.S. Do not use [old construct style](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a reference to the DBConnection in your User class (pass it in in the constructor).

```
private $dbConn;

function __contruct($dbConnRef) {
    $this->dbConn = $dbConnRef;
}

public function storeSelf() {
    $this->dbConn->InsertRecord(...);
}
```